# nullpointerexception on azure blob

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to connect my camera application to the blob storage in window azure. This is how my app works. It takes picture then display it on the imageview at the camera class. there will be a report button where the user will be able to select the picture from the gallery and then send it via the SASURL. Unfortunately, i receive an error at the report class file and i cant find where the error is held.

Below is my camera class code :

```
public class Camera extends Activity{

ImageView iv;
InputStream is;
Button btnR, btnP, btnC;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);

    btnP = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPhoto);
    btnR = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReport);
    btnC = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    btnP.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });

       btnC.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Camera.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

       btnR.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Camera.this, Report.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == 0)
    {
        Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);
    }
}

}
```

Below is my report class code :

```
public class Report extends Activity {
private StorageService mStorageService;
private final String TAG = "BlobsActivity";
private String mContainerName;
private ImageView mImgBlobImage;
private Uri mImageUri;
private AlertDialog mAlertDialog;

Button btnSelect, btnR;
ImageView iv;
TextView tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Get access to the storage service
    StorageApplication myApp = (StorageApplication) getApplication();
    mStorageService = myApp.getStorageService();
    //Get data from the intent that launched this activity
    Intent launchIntent = getIntent();
    mContainerName = launchIntent.getStringExtra("ContainerName");

    //Get the blobs for the selected container
    mStorageService.getBlobsForContainer(mContainerName);       


        setContentView(R.layout.report);
        tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);            
        btnR = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReport);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
        btnSelect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);
        //Set select image handler
        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });

btnR.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    mStorageService.getSasForNewBlob(mContainerName, tv1.getText().toString());
    }
});

    {

    JsonObject blob = mStorageService.getLoadedBlob();
    String sasUrl = blob.getAsJsonPrimitive("sasUrl").toString();
    (new ImageUploaderTask(sasUrl)).execute();
    }
    }

// Fire off intent to select image from gallery
protected void selectImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1111);
}

// Result handler for any intents started with startActivityForResult
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        //handle result from gallary select
        if (requestCode == 1111) {
            Uri currImageURI = data.getData();
            mImageUri = currImageURI;
            //Set the image view's image by using imageUri
            mImgBlobImage.setImageURI(currImageURI);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}   

/***
 * Handles uploading an image to a specified url
 */
class ImageUploaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private String mUrl;
    public ImageUploaderTask(String url) {
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {           
        try {
            //Get the image data
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri, null,null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            String absoluteFilePath = cursor.getString(index);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(absoluteFilePath);
            int bytesRead = 0;
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            while ((bytesRead = fis.read(b)) != -1) {
                bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
            // Post our image data (byte array) to the server
            URL url = new URL(mUrl.replace("\"", ""));
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+ bytes.length);
            // Write image data to server
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(bytes);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            int response = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            //If we successfully uploaded, return true
            if (response == 201
                    && urlConnection.getResponseMessage().equals("Created")) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
        return false;           
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean uploaded) {
        if (uploaded) {
            mAlertDialog.cancel();
            mStorageService.getBlobsForContainer(mContainerName);
        }
    }
}
}
```

LogCat Error :

```
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.testproject/com.example.testproject.Report}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at com.example.testproject.Report.onCreate(Report.java:77)
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-09 05:56:32.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

Comment: what is the line at Report.java 77?

Comment: from which activity u are starting Report?

Comment: report.java class line 77 you mean?
Here it is

            
`String sasUrl = blob.getAsJsonPrimitive("sasUrl").toString();`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K 
I started from the camera class activity

Comment: @user2316009 : currently im not able to find `intent.putExtra("ContainerName",anyvalue)` in  camera class activity? make sure u are passing it

Comment: check whether the blob object is null or not?

Comment: my camera class is actually just a functionality class where it uses the in-built camera to take photo while the report button is used to lead the user to the report class where they start to generate the SASURL for uploading.

Comment: @SankarV how do you check whether the blob object is null?

Comment: Add `if(blob == null) Log.d("Report Activity", "Null"); else Log.d("Report Activity", "Not Null");` after `JsonObject blob = mStorageService.getLoadedBlob();` and check the log

Answer (score 0):

The `blob` object at the line `String sasUrl = blob.getAsJsonPrimitive("sasUrl").toString();` is null. So it is throwing `NullPointerException` because you are trying to invoke a method on a object which is `null`.

Make sure `mStorageService.getLoadedBlob()` not returns `null`.

Comment: how do i not pass through a null blob? i'm not very sure if i missed out any essential codes.

Comment: sorry dude i don't know about azure.